# How to get response body when testing the status code in WebFlux WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

How do you retrieve the response body when trying to throw an exception based on the returned status code? For instance, lets say I want to throw an exception and reject HTTP 201.

```
client.post().exchange().doOnSuccess(response -> {
    if (response.statusCode().value() == 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

How can I populate the exception with the response's body so I can throw a detailed `WebClientResponseException`?

Should I be using a different method to test the response status code?

**edit:** I am trying to duplicate the following functionality while using `exchange()` instead.

```
client.get()
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(s -> !HttpStatus.CREATED.equals(s),
        MyClass::createResponseException);

//MyClass
public static Mono<WebClientResponseException> createResponseException(ClientResponse response) {
    return response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
            .reduce(DataBuffer::write)
            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return bytes;
            })
            .defaultIfEmpty(new byte[0])
            .map(bodyBytes -> {
                String msg = String.format("ClientResponse has erroneous status code: %d %s", response.statusCode().value(),
                        response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase());
                Charset charset = response.headers().contentType()
                        .map(MimeType::getCharset)
                        .orElse(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                return new WebClientResponseException(msg,
                        response.statusCode().value(),
                        response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(),
                        response.headers().asHttpHeaders(),
                        bodyBytes,
                        charset
                        );
            });
}
```

Answer (score 41):

You could achieve like this by having a custom ExchangeFilterFunction and then hooking this up with WebClient.Builder before you build WebClient.

```
public static ExchangeFilterFunction errorHandlingFilter() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            if(clientResponse.statusCode()!=null && (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError() || clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) ) {
                 return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                         .flatMap(errorBody -> {
                             return Mono.error(new CustomWebClientResponseException(errorBody,clientResponse.statusCode()));
                             });
            }else {
                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
            }
        });
    }
```

You can use the above like this:

```
WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(clientOptions))
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Application")
                .filter(WebClientUtil.errorHandlingFilter())
                .baseUrl("https://httpbin.org/")
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri("/post")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(customObjectReference) )
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(String.class) );
```

So any 4XX or 5XX HttpResponse will actually throw CustomWebClientResponseException and you can configure some global exception handler and do what you like to with this. Atleast using ExchangeFilterFunction you can have global place to handle things like this or add custom headers and stuff too.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. May I suggest you can simplify the `if` with : `clientResponse.statusCode().isError()`

Answer (score 19):

`doOn**` operators are side-effects operators and should be used for logging purposes, for example.

Here, you'd like to implement that behavior at the pipeline level, so `onStatus` would be a better fit here:

```
Mono<ClientHttpResponse> clientResponse = client.post().uri("/resource")
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(httpStatus -> HttpStatus.CREATED.equals(httpStatus), 
        response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body -> new MyException(body)))
    bodyToXYZ(...);
```

Or

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> result = client.post().uri("/resource")
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(String.class))
    .flatMap(entity -> {
        // return Mono.just(entity) or Mono.error() depending on the response 
    });
```

Note that getting the whole response body might not be a good idea if you expect large response bodies; in that case, you'd be buffering in memory large amounts of data.

Comment: Sorry, I actually wanted to use `exchange()` so that I had access to `ClientResponse`. Can you perform the same functionality as `onStatus()` in some other way, since that method isn't available?

Comment: added an alternative solution that might fit your use case, although I don't know why you'd specifically like access to ClientResponse. Would you like to set that up as an `ExchangeFilterFunction` in your client?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully provide a clearer picture of what I'm after.

Comment: @BrianClozel what is a good practice for operating with a large response body?

Comment: @BrianClozel I followed your approach of handling the onStatus, but its getting swollowed i think....perhaps you got some idea? and i can send you my code?

Comment: Could you ask a new question with all the required details? I’d be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of trial and error got me the following that appears to do the trick.

```
Mono<ClientResponse> mono = client.get().exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> {
            if (HttpStatus.CREATED.equals(response.statusCode())) {
                return Mono.just(response);
            } else {
                return response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
                        .reduce(DataBuffer::write)
                        .map(dataBuffer -> {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                            dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                            return bytes;
                        })
                        .defaultIfEmpty(new byte[0])
                        .flatMap(bodyBytes -> {
                            String msg = String.format("ClientResponse has erroneous status code: %d %s", response.statusCode().value(),
                                    response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase());
                            Charset charset = response.headers().contentType()
                                    .map(MimeType::getCharset)
                                    .orElse(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                            return Mono.error(new WebClientResponseException(msg,
                                    response.statusCode().value(),
                                    response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(),
                                    response.headers().asHttpHeaders(),
                                    bodyBytes,
                                    charset
                                    ));
                        });
            }
        })
        .retry(3);
final CompletableFuture<ClientResponse> future = mono.toFuture();
```

Comment: Thanks! For debugging this is fine. Be ware that databuffer needs to be released after reading, so response body is consumed, thus `bodyToMono()` will return null.